# Zooming in ComboBox not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that scans an image to display on the application. After the image is scanned, I have the option to zoom the image. There's a combo box on the application that display the zoom percentage as well.

I can zoom fine using my mouse wheel and the combo box % changes accordingly which is fine. The problem happens if I manually select the combo box and select a zoom percentage, say 50%, then there's no changes at all.

Code:

```
private void ImageBox_ZoomLevelsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FillZoomLevels();
}

private void ZoomComboBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void FillZoomLevels()
{
    ZoomComboBox.Items.Clear();

    foreach (int zoom in ImageBox.ZoomLevels)
        ZoomComboBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}%", zoom));
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are we talking about [tag:winforms] or [tag:wpf]? Please tag your question accordingly. And I guess you need the `SelectedItemChanged` or `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox`, not the `Click`  event.

Comment: @RenéVogt My bad, it's winforms. Already edited

Comment: @RenéVogt Is there a zoom in function to work with this?

Comment: You said *I can zoom fine using my mouse wheel and the combo box % changes accordingly which is fine*. So the real question is, does it work fine or not? or you don't even know how to zoom an image which contradicts what you said earlier?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε It works fine using mouse wheel to scroll. But when i click the combo box to manually select the zoom %, say 50% zoom, nothing changes.

Comment: @RenéVogt did answer to use `SelectedItemChanged` or `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of `click`

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε There's no SelectedItemChanged event but I'll try using the IndexChanged event. Then there comes, what do I need to add in the event ?

Comment: The same code you used when you zoomed with the mouse wheel but for a specific value not the `delta` of the scrolling.

Comment: I couldn't find the event for MouseWHeel that is responsible for zooming it though. I don't know where is it

Answer (score 0):

When there is more than one control on the `Panel`, and the `ScrollBars` are shown, the `MouseWheel` event of the `Panel` would be raised, but if there's only a `PictureBox` on  the `Panel` whose `Image` large enough to make the panel's `ScrollBars` visible, then the `MouseWheel` event of the `Panel` won't be raised, instead, the Form's `MouseWheel` event fires.

In the following sample, I just add a `PictureBox` onto the `Panel` without any other controls added, set a large `Image` to the `PictureBox` which make the `Panel`'s `ScrollBars` invisible, since there's only one control on the panel, the `MouseWheel` event of  the `Panel` won't be raised, but the Form's `MouseWheel` event be raised, we handle this event instead, handle the Form's `KeyDown` and KeyUp events as well.

Furthermore, set the SizeMode of the `PictureBox` to **StretchImage** instead of `AutoSize`, thus when we change the size of the `PictureBox`, the `Image` in the `PictureBox` will resize to fit the `PictureBox`.

The `PictureBox.Scale()` method won't help you in this screnario, change the size of the `PictureBox` instead.

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool ctrlKeyDown;
    bool shiftKeyDown;

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ctrlKeyDown = false;
        this.shiftKeyDown = false;

        //If there's only PictureBox control on the panel, the MouseWheel event of the form raised
        //instead of the MouseWheel event of the Panel.
        this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form4_MouseWheel);
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form4_KeyDown);
        this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Form4_KeyUp);

        //this is important for zooming the image
        this.pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

    void Form4_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ctrlKeyDown = e.Control;
        this.shiftKeyDown = e.Shift;
    }

    void Form4_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ctrlKeyDown = e.Control;
        this.shiftKeyDown = e.Shift;
    }

    void Form4_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsGoUp = e.Delta > 0 ? true : false;

        if (this.ctrlKeyDown)
        {
            if (IsGoUp && this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value > 5)
            {
                this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value -= 5;
            }

            if (!IsGoUp && this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value < this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum - 5)
            {
                this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value += 5;
            }
        }
        else if (this.shiftKeyDown)
        {
            int hStep = (int)(this.pictureBox2.Image.Width * 0.02);
            int vStep = (int)(this.pictureBox2.Image.Height * 0.02);
            if (IsGoUp)
            {
                this.pictureBox2.Width += hStep;
                this.pictureBox2.Height += vStep;
            }
            else
            {
                this.pictureBox2.Width -= hStep;
                this.pictureBox2.Height -= vStep;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsGoUp && this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Value > 5)
            {
                this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Value -= 5;
            }

            if (!IsGoUp && this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Value < this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum - 5)
            {
                this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Value += 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow your solution